# How do I write data to a simple uitable in an octave gui?

Tags: octave

I am trying to write a callback function that would write a state to a uitable in octave.  I have modified demouicontrol.m from [https://wiki.octave.org/Uicontrols](https://stackoverflow.com) with,

```
h.stage_table = uitable("units","normalized",
                                     "position", [0.0 0.0 0.20 0.40],
                                      "ColumnName",{},"RowName",{},
                                      "ColumnWidth",{1,1,1},
                                      "data",d=['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E'; ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']');
```

I would like to write an 'X' or anything else to show the completion of a stage, (as the state changes.)  I've looked over the documentation and didn't find an easy way of doing this.  I'm new to gui design, and I'm also not particularly married to updating a table as way to signify the state or stage.  Any other ideas would be welcome, that would indicate that stage of the design process (for the user) is complete.

On this problem, I've been primarily looking thru the uitable documentation so far, looking for a (relatively) simple way to write an X or anything to indicate the current state, of what (will be) the design process.

Or, given

```
    f = figure ();
d = reshape (1:9, [3, 3]);
d=['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E'; ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '];
```

Is there a simple way of overwriting a '' with an 'X' ?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you trying to update the 'data' of the table? If yes, I believe you can simply `set( h.stage_table, 'data', newdata )`

Comment: That did the trick, (writing out all possible states and using a case statement to update.)  Thank you!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. since this is a Q&A site, feel free to answer your own question and provide details for the sake of future users coming with the same problem. :)